# Find usages of static method from sub classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have a popular base class which has a static method `BaseStaticMethod()` and its behavior changes depending on the subclass from which it is invoked:

`SubClass1.BaseStaticMethod()` is not the same as `SubClass2.BaseStaticMethod()`

I would then like to find all the usages of the method just for a particular subclass (E.G. `SubClass2.BasicStaticMethod()`.

I cannod do a text search for `SubClass2.BasicStaticMethod()` because sometime is invoked without the subclass identifier and it will miss some usages.

Is there a way to achieve this in Visual Studio with ReSharper?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Derived1.Create();
        Derived2.Create();

        new Derived1().Save();
        new Derived2().Save();
    }
}

internal class Base<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Create() => new T();

    public void Save() { }
}

internal class Derived1 : Base<Derived1> { }
internal class Derived2 : Base<Derived2> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Advanced Find Usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Usages_Advanced.html), which shows a dialog that you can use to change scope, and also the target - for instance methods, you can choose between e.g. the interface or the base class. I'm not sure how it would work with static methods, as they're not actually overrides.

Alternatively, rename the base class method, do your find usages and rename it back.

Comment: Unfortunately it's really bad designed, Advanced Find Usages doesn't work and the inheritors are not overriding/re-declaring the method, they are just using the base class one.